# SharePoint 2013 workflow stuck in started stage

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio-2012, workflow-manager

I got the setup recently with workflow client and manager installed(on different servers).
I started with developing a simplest of the workflow with just one activity "WriteToHistory".
But upon starting the workflow it is getting stuck in "started" stage like forever.

I am not able to pin point the cause

Can it be configuration issue?

Can it be CU update issue? Currently the installed version is 15.0.4569.1506

The user whose credentials I am using have farm admin and site collection administrator right, also part of workflow service application administrator.

As far as configuration is concerned I can see the 2013 workflow option in SharePoint designer, upon clicking the workflow service application I can see "Workflow is Connected" message

Comment: Do you have the workflow history on the web where you run your workflow? Additionally have you checked the status indicator on the workflow? (click the workflow and hover or click mouse over little exclamation sign) Do you end the workflow with transition to end workflow stage?

Comment: Yes martin, The workflow history list is in place, status indicator shows "activity is in progress".

Comment: My guess is that there is some issue in the communication between the workflow manager and client, when I am installing them in different servers(recommended way), I am facing the above issue, but when i am using them in same machine they run just fine

Comment: Can you try running workflow using standard user account with full control on that list.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same issue, here's how I resolved it:

First check the Troubleshooting section here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588(v=office.15)

mainly, my issue was was related to this:
"The user who deploys and runs a workflow must be added to the **User Profile service**. Check the User Profile service application page in Central Administration to confirm that the user you are using to validate workflow installation is in the User Profile service."

I installed the latest Cumulative Updates

then, all i did is adding the user that I'm using to create and publish workflows to the **User Profile Service**, and checked the Full Control Box.

that point was one of the detailed points in this link check it out:
http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2014/02/01/sharepoint-2013-workflows-are-not-working-issue/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

By default, the workflow doesn’t have permissions to access the list where the Workflows generally run at permission level equivalent to write. Also , The user doesn’t have Contribute permission on the list.

I think you click on the information icon to check the detail error you can also check similar scenario at this link [The Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / Elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read, there are several reasons workflows will get stuck on started. My particular situation might have been one of two (or multiple/all) things:
1. The ciphers on workflow manager did not match the front-end servers
2. SSL and TLS Settings did not marry up.

After we removed the ciphers and TLS settings and reset them back to what we had before, our workflows started working again.